# IllegalArgumentexception index out of range groovy

Tags: java, groovy, indexing

I am getting an illegalargumentexception when I try to call the index. It keeps saying the index is out of range when it is set to 0.

```
sheetIndex = 0
sampleStartIndex = (37)
def MIDCellIndex = CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("I")
HSSFCell cell,containerCell, wellCell = null
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex)




Caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(HSSFWorkbook.java:429)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(HSSFWorkbook.java:825)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(HSSFWorkbook.java:73)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook$getSheetAt$0.call(Unknown Source)
at com.genologics.client.bartender.midscript.main(CSVandManifestGenerator.groovy:50)
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a new workbook.

New workbooks do not have sheets

You need to create a sheet in the workbook rather than trying to get one